# Python psycopg2 error when changing environment to os x

Tags: python, macos, psycopg2

I have this error when i perform the following task,

> results = db1.executeSelectCommand(siteSql, (),)
>   TypeError: unbound method executeSelectCommand() must be called with dbConnn instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

My code is as follows:

```
class dbConnn:
    db_con  = None
    execfile("/Users/usera/Documents/workspace/testing/src/db/db_config.py")

    def executeSelectCommand(self,sql,ip):
        #psycopg connection here.
```

I use this class here:

```
from db import dbConnections

db1 = dbConnections.dbConnn

siteSql = 'select post_content from post_content_ss order by RANDOM() limit 500' #order by year,month ASC'
results = db1.executeSelectCommand(siteSql, (),)
```

In windows, there don't seem to have a problem with this? God, it must be really elementary but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db1 = dbConnections.dbConnn
```

Here you assign *the class* `dbConn` to the variable `db1`. You probably wanted to create a new instance instead:

```
db1 = dbConnections.dbConnn()
```